# EXTJS5 MVVM: Get global controller from view controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

From a global controller, I can easily get a reference to another global controller with

```
this.getController('TargetController');
```

However, within the context of a view controller, how can I get a reference to that same controller?  i.e.:

```
Ext.define('myCoolApp.view.SomeNeatController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.someneat',

    // this is bound to a button click event, let's say.
    onClick: function(button) {

        // How to get a reference to a global controller here? 
        // this.getController('TargetController'); is not defined
        // on the view controller....

    }

});
```

Probably something simple I'm missing, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In 99.99% cases, if you need to get a reference to a global controller in Ext JS 5 you're doing something wrong. What was the intent?

Comment: I thought someone was going to ask this. :)  I have to retrieve some data from a webservice (google drive api) and I have this logic (with all of the oauth2 stuff) nicely abstracted into a contoller from a previous ExtJS4 project.  I need to kick off that data retrieval from an event that I'm handling in the view controller. It might not be the 100% ideal architecture, but refactoring working, tested, (and pretty) code just to fit a design pattern is even less desirable, in my opinion.

Comment: Controller event domain is the tool to use here. See my posts: http://nohuhu.org/development/controller-events-in-ext-js-4-2/ and http://nohuhu.org/development/using-synchronous-bidirectional-communication-with-controllers/

Comment: Neat.  That wasn't on my radar before.  One small bug in the ext 5.0.0 documentation:  The Ext.app.EventDomain class lists the controller domain as all classes extending from Ext.app.Controller.  The view controllers do NOT extend from Ext.app.Controller, (though both share a common Ext.app.BaseController base) but the controller event domain DOES listen to events fired from view controllers.  Anyways, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling getController on your namespace should work:

```
myCoolApp.app.getController('TargetController');`
```

Comment: I am also looking for an answer for this one, but can't find. 

Isn't this a global call? Your controller in this case HAS to know that you have a myCoolApp and a TargetController, which makes it very dependent of these things. 

I don't like this solution.

Comment: I don't like the necessity of knowing the global controller in the view controller in the first place. The app needs a redesign if you need it. I've written a couple of really big apps in Ext 5 and Ext 6 and I've never needed it.